# Separating periodic solutions from list of solutions in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am solving a second order differential equation using the following code

```
eqns = {x''[t] + (a - 2*q*Cos[2*t])*x[t] == 0, x'[0] == 1, x[0] == 1};

sol2 = ParametricNDSolve[eqns, x, {t, 100}, {q, a}];

z = Table[{(x[q, a][t] /. sol2), {q, a, t}}, {q, 0, 1.5, 0.05},
          {a, -0.8, 0.5, 0.05}, {t, 10}] // Flatten[#, 2] &
```

Now I am listing only those elements that are the solutions at `t = 60`,

```
list = Part[z, Range[60, Length[z], 60]];
```

Now I will select some of the elements from the above list using a criteria given below

```
limx = Select[list, -15 <= #[[1]] <= 15 &];
```

Now, the solutions of the differential equation are periodic as well as those which shoot to infinity, the criteria I have written above defines the amplitude, that my solutions are within the given amplitude, but it does not give me the information about periodicity of the  solutions, what I want is first I select those solutions which are periodic and then apply the criteria for amplitude, I do not know how to do it.

Comment: But I do not want to use inbuilt functions.